# Characteristic of the ring $(\mathcal{P}(\emptyset), \Delta, \cap)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Characteristic of the ring $(\mathcal{P}(\emptyset), \Delta, \cap)$?

If $0=1$ it says to have no characteristic.
additive identity $(0)=\{\}$
multiplicative identity $(1)=\{\}$
so $0=1$.

Is my reasoning correct? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The ring is of characteristic 1. Formally, consider a ring $R$, and consider the unique ring homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z} \to R$. The kernel of $f$ is an ideal $I$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, we can write $I = (n)$ for some $n$. In particular, there is a unique nonnegative $n$ such that $(n) = I$. This $n$ is the characteristic of $R$.

Now we see that $P(\emptyset)$ is the zero ring, so $I = \mathbb{Z} = (1)$. Therefore, the ring is of characteristic 1.

Answer (score 0):

It has characteristic $1$, since that is the minimum amount of times you need to sum $1$ until reaching $0$.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought. But then I got confused because it says if  0=1 it says to have no characteristic.

Comment: @Annai Who says? some book? which book? if the book you are reading says that the ring has no characteristic, that is not a standard definition of characteristic. With the usual definition, the ring has characteristic $1$.

Comment: Not sure. It's a pdf.  This is what it says; 1s = 0s then (S,+,.) is said to have no characteristic.